# cli tool in docker container is slow

Tags: performance, docker

What shoul I expect performance wise when using docker for cli tool?
Seems like when I try running this tool in docker - it is a lot slower. Am I doing it wrong?

So I ahve a test.html file with this content:

```
<html><!--sdfsf--></html>
```

Installed on my box - very fast:

```
$ time html-minifier --remove-comments <test.html
<html></html>
real    0m0.098s
user    0m0.088s
sys 0m0.013s
```

Running in docker -> takes a lot longer:

```
time docker run -i chuyskywalker/node-html-minifier html-minifier --remove-comments <test.html
<html></html>

real    0m1.061s
user    0m0.019s
sys 0m0.012s
```

EDIT: My machine is Fedora Linux 25. Docker was installed from docker official repositories.

Comment: What is "your box"? How was Docker installed?

Comment: my box = my computer (Fedora linux 25). Docker was installed from docker repos.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple things to note here:

1. Docker on macOS or Windows is actually running in a virtual machine. This virtual machine will come with some overhead and may also be limited in how many actual CPUs and memory it has access to.
2. Docker container do have a startup time (which can be 1 second or more).
3. If you are mounting volumes or piping in data to standard input, it can be slower as it has to travel through the Docker client to the Docker host.

You didn't mention how Docker was installed or the host platform. But if you are on Windows or macOS then #1 and #3 will definitely account for some of the time.

One thing you can do is move the `time` command inside the container (if the utility is available in the image) to get a closer representation of the actual process time:

```
docker run -i chuyskywalker/node-html-minifier time html-minifier --remove-comments <test.html
```

Comment: My box is Fedora linux  - I think your #2 point is probably the issue here. So I think I need to try launching docker container as a daemon or something to avoid it.